# how to detect if a point lies in a non-rectangular region in a 2D numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2D array. Lets suppose that it has some connected region which is non rectangular. Consider the following example

```
 array([[1, 1, 2, 2],\
        [0, 1, 0, 1],\
        [3, 0, 1, 4],\
        [0, 3, 1, 1]])
```

In above array all the ones are connected. I know all these coordinates which are stored lets say as a 2d numpy array or a list of elements (x,y).

Now I want to query that if an arbitrary points lies in this area. The point could also be a float.

In case of float coordinates the values will be round of to the nearest integer pixel value.

Thanks a lot

Comment: So you have a coordinate and want to know if it is in a list of coordinates?  For membership testing I would use a set instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
areas = array([[1, 1, 2, 2],\
        [0, 1, 0, 1],\
        [3, 0, 1, 4],\
        [0, 3, 1, 1]])

def is_in_area(x,y, area_num):
    return areas[round(x), round(y)] == area_num
```

Is this what you're going for?

Of course, you might want some bounds checking in there.

Comment: cool man this is exactly what I was intending to do... I was just thinking differently. The solution was so simple. Thank you very much.